# Is there an online source of raw contour data?

Tags: open-source-gis, contour

My goal is to get a vector image (SVG preferably) of a local mountain. The data clearly exists, but as an armchair cartographer without access to raw layer data I've been reduced to combing the web for sources of just contours.

I usually find it mixed with relief shading and land ownership boundaries which make the image recognition (live tracing in Illustrator, for example) quite difficult.

Has anyone found a mapping site with a web interface that provides such a thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download raw contours lines from the [National Map Viewer](http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/viewer/).  I like to download by bounding box (button highlighted in red).

[image]

Comment: It is worth noting that in addition to having a layer of the contour lines, this site allows you to download a DEM.  I would venture that there are more areas where a DEM is available, than there are areas where the actual contours have been generated.  The DEM can then be used to generate contours at a chosen interval, using your preferred GIS package.

Answer (score 1):

## Download as SVG

This tool lets you [download the topographical map of any area as an SVG](https://buntinglabs.com/tools/download-topo-map-contour-lines), no signup needed.

[image]

It seems like the National Map Viewer website has been updated and no longer allows the download of vector contour lines.